# Got error while updating (sudo apt update)

Tags: 20.04, updates, openvpn, mongodb

```
Err:17 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg                                                   
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 58712A2291FA4AD5
Hit:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                             
Get:2 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease [149 kB]                     
Err:2 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done     
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 58712A2291FA4AD5
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I was installing mongodb on my machine, and got these errors while entering `sudo apt update`

Comment: It looks like you're using an expired Xenial repo on Focal.

Comment: @ArturMeinild can you be more precise? can you help me solve this?

Comment: There are [official installation instructions on MongoDB website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). The repo need to match your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArturMeinild where is the list of these updates like commands. Might be I have to delete mongo's lines and reinstall it?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 20.04? If you need help with repos, please post the entire contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the content of all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'`
how to solve this one?

Comment: It looks like you have a repo for 32-bit architecture - remove that as well.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have deleted that openvpn link. So now i do not have any errors. But will my openvpn3 update?

Comment: Enter the correct repo for your release - see here: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, guys. In **Software & Update** go to **Other Software** and as @AArturMeinild said I removed **Xenial repo mongo..**. So after that I do not get any errors.